# Django OneToOneField or ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-models, model

My `models.py`:

```
class User:
  // fields ...

class Post:
  // fields ...

class Comment:
  news = models.ForeignKey(Post)
  user = models.???(User)
```

Each `Post` can have any number of `Comment`s. *But for each `Post`, I want a user to have only one `Comment`.* How do I model this?

I cannot do `user = models.OneToOneField(User)` because in that case a `User` will be able to comment only once across all `Post`s.

Also I cannot do `user = models.ForeignKey(User)` because in that case a `User` will be able to post as many comments as he likes on a single `Post` which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are interested in the [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#unique-together) model meta option:

> Sets of field names that, taken together, must be unique.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    news = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('news', 'user')
```

Your `user` field can then be simply a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Great! Also please suggest how do I learn Django. Do I just wade through all the tweaks, options and configurations? There are sooo many options :(.

Comment: Obviously I cannot cover this in a comment, not even an answer. There are many books and tutorials, but a good start is always the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/) which is pretty extensive for this level of questions. The more the options the more the capabilities.